# How to invert boolean arrays inside another array with map and forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to reverse and invert arrays inside a two-dimensional array.

```js
let a = [[true, false, false], [false, true, true]];
```

I've made a function that takes in two-dimensional array `a` and does a `forEach` on it. This takes each inner array and reverses it. I then try to take the indivual array that was just reversed and try to do `map` on it to invert each value inside the array (`bool => !bool`).

This function seems to work up to the `reverse()`, but I can't figure out why the `map()` doesn't seem to work. Is it impossible to chain looping / iterative arrow functions like this?

```js
var reverseInvert = a => {
  a.forEach(arr => arr.reverse().map(bool => !bool));
  return a;
};
```

expected result:

```
[[ true, true, false], [false, false, true]]
```

actual result:

```
[[false, false, true], [true, true, false]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` always creates a *new* array - the existing array will not be mutated. Either `.map` to create a new larger array:

```js
let a = [[true, false, false], [false, true, true]];
var reverseInvert = a => {
  const newA = a.map(arr => arr.reverse().map(bool => !bool));
  return newA;
};
console.log(reverseInvert(a));
```

Or, if you want to mutate (not recommended unless necessary), you'll have to explicitly reassign the new mapped inner array to the index on the outer array:

```js
let a = [[true, false, false], [false, true, true]];
var reverseInvert = a => {
  a.forEach((arr, i, outerArr) => {
    outerArr[i] = arr.reverse().map(bool => !bool)
  });
  return a;
};
console.log(reverseInvert(a));
```

Comment: deleting my previous comments because I forgot to comment out my old code after I added new code in. I'm an idiot =)     Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As CertainPerformance pointed out map method returns a new array and you are not assigning it:

```
 var reverseInvert = ([...a]) => a.reverse().map(bool => !bool);
```